# Detect variable from another component and pass it to different component

Tags: angular

I'm fairly new to Angular.
I'm building up this application.
The structure like this.

```
dock component --- header
               |
               --- body --- message
               |
               --- input
```

I want to watch if variable is changing from 'message' component.
If it gets changed, I wanna do something in 'header' component.
Is there any way for 'header' component to know that?

Someone told me to use event emitter, subscribe, and make observable object.
I made event emitter in the 'message' component, and don't know what to do afterwards.

Thanks,

```
export class MessageComponent {

  @Input() message;
  @Output() connectedAgentNameEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  // connectedAgentName: string = "";
  // connectedAgentNameChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.message.type == 'ReceivedMessage') {
      this.connectedAgentNameEvent.emit(this.message.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Other thing I can think of is when variable gets changed in 'message' component, then I do event emitter to 'body' component' and to 'dock' component, and finally pass it down to 'header' with @Input()

Comment: If your components have a (grand)parent-child relationship you can use the @Input/@Output decorator. However, if the depth is bigger than 2, I would suggest a service with a subject. Since you're new to Angular, you may find helpful the following article on component communication: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-component-communication-81e5e02c6cbe

Answer (score 3):

My go to method of cross component communication is [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject). To set it up, first create a [service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services), cli: `ng generate service foo`. Imagine services as cross component data/function sharing pool. Then create a subject in your service by adding:

```
 messageSubject = new Subject;
```

Then go to message component, import service and define it in constructor

```
import { FooService} from '../../foo.service';
constructor(private fooService: FooService);
```

When message component is ready to emit just call `next()` method on subject from imported service and add your data as argument:

```
this.fooService.messageSubject.next(newMessage);
```

Now go to header component and also import your new service. After that create a new variable of type subscription and assign it your subject with subscribe `method` on it:

```
messageSubscription : Subscription;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messageSubscription = this.fooService.messageSubject.subscribe((newMessage) => {
      // work with recieved data here
   });
}
```

Now each time next method is called on your subject, everyone subscribe (header in your case) will be immediately informed and receive latest data. Bear in mind that this way you may have many subscriber listening to data all over your app with very little hussle. After you are done with subscription (when you leave the page) you should unsubscribe from your subscriptions to prevent memory leakages. For that just add ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.messageSubscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

> 

I understand this may be a lot to digest but if you are planning to use angular, the sooner you learn services and subjects, the better.

Comment: Thanks Max. I have a quick question. So thing is the data comes from 'message' component. In this scenario, how do I make it as Service?

Comment: I mean, I wanted to put that variable in Service, but can't think of any idea to do that, because the variable exists in 'message' component.

Comment: Oh..I think I misunderstood your points.. I'll apply that to my codes. Thanks a lot, Max!

Comment: Just in case, I´ll sum up. Service are independent units and are used to offer “services” to various components. These services could range from simple data entry to other complex functionalities.  In your case it serves as a bridge for component communication. The huge advantage is that you need to "bubble up" data, with input/output, through whole component branch to get it to header making your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

So this is where the container/component architecture comes into play. The idea is that you have a container component which is responsible for fetching most of the data your child components need. The child components get this data, and emit any new changes, via `Input` and `Output` respectively.

So in your case then, you would define a method in your dock which will be passed down to your Message component via html ex:

- **Dock Component.ts**

  myMethod(event: any) {
  //In here, event can be named whatever you want, and its type should be
  //the type of the object or data that is being sent up. any is of course a catch
  //all. Set your data as needed.

  }
- **Dock Component.html**

  <body-component (myMethod)="myMethod($event)">

Here you are defining the output variable, which I've elected to call `myMethod` in the body component as well. Note the `$event` in the signature, this is needed.

- **Body Component.ts**

  @Output() myMethod: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
- **Body Component.html**

  <message-component (myMethod)="myMethod.emit($event)">

In here we are saying that its `Output` in the body component will immediately emit whatever the message comes from the message-component. This is because I am using we don't really need to do anything with the `Output` in the body component. If we do, we can define our own method that accepts the result, have it update it as needed, then emit.

- **Message Component.ts**

Here we do it the way you have it, where we just emit the result.

**EDIT**

I've made this very simplistic stackblitz to show how you can make use of this pattern. So the layout here is as follows (going to use JSON style notation here)

```
Container: {
 Component-One: {
   Component-Two: {}
 },
 Component-Three: {}
}
```

From here Component-Two has a button that emits a value up to component one, which then goes up to the Container. In the container it updates the value of the property called `text` which is an `Input` to Component Three which resides within the `Container`.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzepxi?file=src/app/container/componentThree/component-three.component.ts

Comment: So you're saying that the variable fires off from Message to Body, and then to Dock, and down to Header, right? 
Thanks for your input, @SomeStudent. I'll try that.

Comment: @AndyKo, pretty much. It goes from the child to the overall parent component and from there the parent can update the values it has for input. Imagine a child telling their parents something (so they emitted their response), and then from there the parent can create a new input and pass it down to other children.

Comment: @AndyKo, I just added a stackblitz for you to see a very simplistic example of this pattern in action